# MonoTouch.Dialog: Setting Entry Alignment for EntryElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Using the `EntryElement` to enter data as is results in the data being entered being aligned sort of in the middle.

How do I specify that the entry should be right aligned on an iPad.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried overriding `CreateTextField` on `EntryElement` ?

That should give you complete control on how to create the `UITextField` being used for the entry part of the element.

**Update** Notice that if you override CreateTextField, you should also override the Cellkey property, to ensure that this cell is not shared through the UITableView cell-sharing machinery with other EntryElements.

Of course you'll need to know the right size before being called (or delay settings some properties until you know for sure).