# Right aligned EntryElement

Tags: iphone, c, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Any sample on making `EntryElement` align to the right?

I can't figure out how to inherit/override the `EntryElement`.

Thanks,
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks near identical [MonoTouch.Dialog: Setting Entry Alignment for EntryElement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7908991/220643)

See my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7910151/220643) about overriding `CreateTextField`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Why not implement it? New EntryElement(caption, placeholder, value, alignment)? I'm sure more people could benefit from this. :)

Comment: You can fill a bug report (priority enhancement) in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com Personally what I **really* like in MonoTouch.Dialog is the ability to customize everything (e.g. create my own `Element` that match what is being represented) from a small library (compared to not being able to customize anything from a large library ;-). That being said there's a lot that can be done to enhance the library so your feedback is welcome :-)